# How can I make more efficient use of findall() in StringDistances

Tags: julia

I have a dataframe - comb - describing a set of items. One of the fields in the DataFrame contains the geographic location (UK Electoral Wards) of each item. There are just under 9000 records that have accumulated over 30 years and, over that time, many wards have been created, deleted or changed name. However, some wards have remained the same but have different names. For example, St has become St., and has become &, Pembroke West has become Pembroke: West. I am seeking near matches in the list using StringDistances. I compare every element in the list with all later elements to find near matches:

```
for (i, s) in enumerate(comb.WD22NM)
    MatchIndex = findall(lowercase(s), lowercase.(comb[i:length(comb.WD22NM), :WD22NM]), TokenMax(Levenshtein()); min_score=0.95)
    if length(MatchIndex) > 1
        MatchIndex .+= (i-1)
        deleteat!(MatchIndex, (j for j in eachindex(MatchIndex) if MatchIndex[j] == i))
        @printf(io_buf,"%5.4i %-50.48s %-75s \n", i, s, comb.WD22NM[MatchIndex])
    end
end
```

Here is an example of the kind of near matches I mean:

`4217 Redruth Central, Carharrack & St Day               ["Redruth Central, Carharrack & St. Day", "Redruth Central, Carharrack  St Day"]`

This process is very slow, taking many minutes to process 9000 records.

I found this response elsewhere:

> But still, this is a bit wasteful, since you are making two copies of the same column, and are allocating five intermediate vectors that you don't need. You should try to use a predicate function to avoid this, like e.g. here:
>
> findall(x->x in (0.5, 1.0), p[:,50])
> or
>
> findall(x->x==0.5||x==1, p[:,50])
> On top of this, you can use view to avoid allocations due to p[:,50]:
>
> findall(x->x==0.5||x==1, view(p, :,50)

I couldn't make the predicate function work and nor could I take a `view`. I can't figure out how many intermediate vectors I am calling into being.

I'm both new to programming and new to Julia and wonder if anyone can suggest ways to speed this up.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a research area known as _Record Linkage_ (see the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage)). There are many possible approaches to speed up the matching. One would be to set a maximum character length difference (e.g., 5), sort all items by length, and compare in windows of +/-5 (for example a string of length 20 can never match a string of length 30 in this case so you don't need to try). Another approach is to clean the text first (remove numbers etc.) and compare in groups based on the first character only.

Comment: I've experimented a bit. It seems like the real time penalty comes from using `TokenMax`. If I exclude the TokenMax qualification, `@time` on the for-loop gives 
`8.303817 seconds (6.92 M allocations: 1.572 GiB, 11.47% gc time, 8.06% compilation time)`
If I include TokenMax (but make no other changes), I get
`1230.752270 seconds (7.00 G allocations: 411.179 GiB, 10.00% gc time, 0.20% compilation time)`
which is a huge time penalty.

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn. My approach is a bit brute force, I admit. Your comment has stimulated some ideas about other approaches. For example, it seems likely that wards are co-terminus with regions or even local authority areas. If I could group by either of these, I can significantly reduce the scope of each findall request. I'll give that a go!